# Problems with passing form details in PHP using POST

Tags: php, html, forms, post

This is a piece of code on home.php

```
<form action="./Login" method="post">
Email Address: <br />
<input type="text" name="username" tabindex="1" /><br />
Password: <br />
<input type="password" name="password" tabindex="2" /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="home" value="yes" />
<div class="options">
<input type="submit" value="" name="LoginCheck" class="submit_n" />
</div>
</form>
```

On submitting `isset($_POST['LoginCheck'])` on `login.php` return false.

I usually write the form part & processing part on the same file & then this seems to work correctly. However for this case i.e processing on other page this does not seem to work.

This is probably a minor problem but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Logan it works if he has multiviews ( http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html#multiviews ) enabled in apache and working in a case insensitive system, I'm not sure this is the case though.

Comment: Input with type="submit" won't be included in the POST data and thus won't show up in the $_POST array

Comment: How come the same code works when everything is on the same page: if(isset($_POST['LoginCheck'])) { //process code } else { //form code as posted }

Comment: @softcr the clicked submit button (that has a name) will be sent.

Comment: @Gaurav can u provide a `print_r($_POST);` output, also, is the button on the page being clicked normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working. I have no clue why this worked? Kindly Explain!!

By default all directory access is to index.php [As configured by me in Apache]

So when I say action="./Login" it would go the index.php but for some reason wont remember where it cam from so the POST data isn't there.

I changed it to action="./Login/index.php" & now everything works fine. WHY??????

Comment: Cuz the browser will try to post to `/Login`, the server knows it's a directory, will redirect the browser to `/Login/`, on the redirect, the browser won't do the post again. Adding a slash to the action should be enough. and BTW! why didn't you set the action to the full path of the action page from the start!

Answer (score 1):

No value for the `LoginCheck` submit input. Per [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) `isset` "Determine if a variable is set and **is not NULL**"

Comment: But won't that return true for the `isset` call? It's set, but has no value.

Comment: @aularon: I've (implicitly) addressed that in my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be written action="../login.php" instead action="./login.php"

Comment: Nopes. action field is correct. I also know this because it goes to the right page login.php & displays some content which is there in the else loop.

Comment: then Gourav once u write u r full action path..it seems like a bug in u r action path..try with full action path..but u said u r reaching to  u r action page..then check u r action page with print_r($_POST) it will help u to check the post values

Comment: But in u r code above the submit button has nothing to post any value..so give the submit button any value or remove value=""

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple:

Remove the `value=""`

Web browsers are not required to submit controls that don't have values:

> If a control doesn't have a current
>   value when the form is submitted, user
>   agents are not required to treat it as
>   a successful control.

--HTML4 spec, Section [17.13.2 Successful Controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2)

To clarify, web browsers are required to submit only successful controls, meaning that if the browser opted not to treat the control as successful, the browser can't submit the control.

> A successful control is "valid" for
>   submission.

--HTML4 spec, same section as above

Comment: Nope, still does not work. Not only does removing it not help, but know it also shows Submit text on my button which is an image. The value="" ensures that nothing is printed on the button.

Comment: @Gaurav OT, but you should probably be using a `<button type="submit"><img ...></button>` instead of `<input type="submit" value="">`.

Answer (score -1):

What basically happens is that because you have the value of "LoginCheck" set to "", which is NOTHING, the browser doesn't even send it.

I think if you do a print_r($_POST), you won't even see there as an array key, which is why your isset() fails.

Give it a proper value if you want to do something with it.

Comment: The value field is just to display a name on the button. It is the name field that matters. & As I mentioned if I change action to "home.php" itself & then isset($_POST['LoginCheck']) returns fine & I can process all fields. I don't know why this does not work if a call is made to other page.

Comment: So you basically imply, that it is impossible to post empty values?

Comment: How come the same code works when:

if(isset($_POST['LoginCheck']))
{
//process code
}
else
{
//show form
}

Comment: Not impossible to post empty values, but don't count on them ;)

Comment: Why not use a hidden field with a value of 1?  Do you do some other logic if that button was specifically pressed?

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="home" value="yes" />
as you can see I tried this. Still does not work. No data gets transferred to the other page.